# Do arrays act like pointers when passed to a function in C or C#?

Tags: c#, c, arrays, function, arguments

When an array is passed to an function as an argument in C or C#, does the function or can the function operate on the argument? Like it does on pointers?

Comment: these are two questions, not one. C is one language. C# is another language. i don't know C well, but i know the answer happens to be the same in both languages. but there are so many differences, that care should be taken to treat the languages separately. for instance, sukhvir's source code only compiles in C, not C#. but i'm certain C# passes the variable by reference, not by value, so this answer is the same for both C and C#. but please don't assume this is always the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is for C only

yes it absolutely can . Function treats the array as a pointer

eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

void anyfunction(int array[]){  
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        array[i] = i;
    }
}

int main(){
    int i=0;
    int numbers[SIZE] = {0};

    anyfunction(numbers);

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        printf("%d ",numbers[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

**output:**

```
Notra:Desktop Sukhvir$ ./test
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: i believe sukhvir should comment that his answer is C. C and C# are two (very) different languages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can but Arrays decay into pointers.

> An lvalue [see [question 2.5](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html#2-5)] of type array-of-T which appears in
>   an expression decays (with three exceptions) into a pointer to its
>   first element; the type of the resultant pointer is pointer-to-T
>   because an array is not a "modifiable lvalue,"

(The exceptions are when the array is the operand of a sizeof or & operator, or is a literal string initializer for a character array.)

Comment: i take it you are referring to C, not C#?

Answer (score 1):

Any expression of array type is, in most but not all contexts, implicitly converted to ("decays" to) a pointer to the array object's first element, unless it's the operand of unary `&` or `sizeof` operator.
Recomended reading: [CFAQ-Arrays and Pointers](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: `It decays to pointer when pass to a function (but not always). There are some exceptions like sizeof where it does not decays to pointer. ` - this is wrong - `sizeof` is an operator not a function

Answer (score 1):

In the context of C, the array name points to the base address.

Say, `a[10]` ,to refer the 4th object, ie `a[3]`, this is an equivalent method - `*(a+3)`.

So it gives you an idea how arrays can be used as a pointer.

When you pass the array name to a function as an argument, you are actually passing the base address of the array.

Comment: welcome, Udit. when you add 3 to a pointer in C, does it always add 3 bytes, or does it add 3 * the length of the items you are pointing to? so if you have an array of 2-byte integers, does *(a+3) point to that 4th item or do you need to use *(a+6)? ;) I truly don't know. but i've 'been around the block' enuf to know that this needs to be considered if using *(a+3) in any language.

Comment: Well for your 1st question, when you add 3 to a pointer in C, it would add 3 bytes if it was a pointer to a char :D , okay , coming back to your point, It's the pointer arithmetic I believe.
if you have declared a pointer to an integer, `i+3` would be `i + 3*sizeof(int)` So irrespective of your machine, it'll be pointing at the right element. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

yes absolutely.
 You can use that array in your function as array behaviors.